# Does Kafka modify the segment when a re-election occurs?

Tags: apache-kafka

My understanding is that the segement is `append-only`. But there is this scenario.

> Suppose I have three Brokers, A, B, and C.
>
> Currently, A is the Leader, Both B and C are in the ISR. C persists more data than B. At this point, A fails and B becomes the Leader.

## My question is:

> The `old data` in the question means: The data is persisted by C, but not yet by B. So Producer will resend it (`aks=-1`).

1. when B becomes Leader, will the `old data` in C remain in the `.log` file?
2. When Producer sends the `old data`, is it appended to the end of the `.log` file as new data when C receives it (generating duplicate data)? Or does C reject the data.
3. If `old data` will be appended to the end of the `.Log` file, will this cause the Offset to be discontinuously incremented? How does Kafka solve this?
4. If C rejects this `old data`, what is its judgment logic (simple) for rejecting it? If for some reason the `old data` sent is actually different from the one sent over before. Will this cause confusion in C?

Or maybe there is something wrong with my question and something completely different is happening with Kafka than I thought?

Thanks.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, LEO means `log end offset`. I have edited the question.
Also,`unclean leader election allowed` is not allowed in my scenario.

Comment: If it's not allowed, then B (or C) cannot become the leader if they haven't replicated the latest offsets. Producers aren't sending data to the replicas, only to the leader

Comment: @OneCricketeer In the Kafka documentation. [unclean.leader.election.enable](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_unclean.leader.election.enable) just rejects the Follower that is not in the ISR queue to be the leader. But in my scenario, even though A,B,C are not 100% synchronized, both B and C are in the ISR queue. Is the `unclean leader election allowed`  in your comment from another parameter?

Comment: It's the same config. Maybe I misunderstood your question, then, but it sounded to me like you have acks=-1, so your producer will not wait for a replica to exist, therefore you shouldn't always have all brokers in the ISR. I didn't understand what you mean "B LEO is the smallest"... Smallest of what? If it's a replica, of course it'll be lower than the leader, temporarily... If it doesn't match the leader offset then it's not "in sync", and so shouldn't be able to be made the leader

Comment: @OneCricketeer What I mean is. In the `aks=-1` scenario, B and C are Follower of A. When A hangs, obviously, there is some data that has not finished persisting in C and B, which will be considered as failed by Producer. However, we cannot guarantee that the persistence of B and C is 100% synchronized. Maybe C will have persisted more data than B? I have re-edited the question, and it may be expressed more clearly.

Comment: If B has more data than C, and both have less data than A, then they are not in-sync, so they wouldn't be allowed to become leaders... Maybe this talk covers more what you're looking for https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf18/hardening-kafka-replication/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Page 54 of the PPT was exactly the situation I was hoping to discuss. b broke down. A becomes leader, but by this time, B has persisted r5 . The PPT says these data `needs to be truncated`.  However, if Segement is Append-Only. How can kafka do this. Or does R5 still exist only in memory and not persisted on the disk?

Comment: Segments themselves are append only, but the whole files can still be deleted in order to prevent diverging logs. I'm not really sure on the inner workings of all that, but I don't think the data is available anywhere else, and the only way to really retrieve data from diverged logs is to manually copy those segments files out before they would be removed after leader election, and use DumpLogSegments tool to extract any possible data from the raw bytes

Comment: Also, everything before page 200-ish was how it previously worked (or was thought it should work). This ticket fixed one of problems with the data loss truncation https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7128

Comment: @OneCricketeer I re-read the PPT in its entirety. It solved almost all my questions. it helped me a lot. I also benefited a lot from your answer. Thanks.